# The following code can’t cause a deadlock, and yet I get Transaction ( Process ID 54 ) was deadlocked …

Tags: sql-server, wcf, transactions

Service operation `MyMethod(int id)` retrieves particular row ( based on an `id` parameter ) from a single DB table and just before it returns it also saves that state back to the table. If two calls ( first call happens within transaction **T1** while second within transaction **T2** ) to `MyMethod()` are made at the same time, then service will try to execute the two calls concurrently. Since both **T1** and **T2** try to access same DB table, one of the two transaction will be granted access to the resource, while other should get blocked until the original transaction commits or aborts. But instead I get an exception *Transaction ( Process ID 54 ) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim*

I don’t understand reasoning behind throwing deadlock exception since as far as I can tell there isn’t any danger of a deadlock. For one thing, the two transactions accessed and operated on different rows. Why wasn’t instead the DB resource just locked until original transaction committed or aborted?!

Here is the code:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
    void Process(int id);
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true)]
public class Service : IService
{
    string state_Data = "";

    [OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired = true)]
    public void Process(int id)
    {
        GetState(id);
        Thread.Sleep(6000);
        SaveState(id);
    }


    private void GetState(int id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "data source=localhost; initial catalog=WCF; integrated security=sspi;";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM StateTable WHERE id = @id";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.Read())
                state_Data = reader["State"].ToString();
        }
    }

    private bool SaveState(int id)
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = "data source = localhost; initial catalog=WCF; integrated security=sspi;";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE StateTable SET State=@State WHERE Id = @id";
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = state_Data;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            int ret = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            return ret == 1;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In case this will help, here is client code:

FIRST CLIENT:

```
        ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient("WSDualHttpBinding_IService");

        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            proxy.Process(1);
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

SECOND CLIENT:

```
        ServiceClient proxy = new ServiceClient("WSDualHttpBinding_IService");

        using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            proxy.Process(2);
            scope.Complete();
        }
```

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice your question. I don't know anything about indexes, but I doubt table has any, since sql statement that created the table didn't specify any indexes - CREATE TABLE StateTable (id int PRIMARY KEY,State nvarchar(100))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually this code is a **guaranteed** deadlock. There can be any number of successful `GetState` calls on the same `ID`, all succeeding, since they all acquire (and retain, due to the serializable transaction scope) shared locks and therefore are compatible. Any subsequent attempt to `SaveState` will block, because of the multitude of shared locks are all incompatible with the X lock needed for the update. The next `SaveState` will deadlock. 100% repro, guaranteed, every time.

You should use [optimistic concurrency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control) instead if you care about performance. If performance is irrelevant then the `GetState` should lock the state exclusively, eg. by providing an [XLOCK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx) hint.

Of course, I assume there is a clustered index on `ID` in StateTable.

Comment: I know almost nothing of transaction isolation, so forgive me if question is rather stupid. If I understand you correctly, the two transactions receive locks L1 and L2, which enables them to concurently access (read) same DB table.And when the two transaction try to concurrently call SaveState, they both try to acquire lock X. So why doesn't SQL server "give" lock X to one of the two transactions,and when that transaction releases lock X, the other transaction can then acquire it? Thus, I still don't understand why this needs to cause a deadlock?!

Comment: 1) T1 requests and is granted S lock. 2) T2 requests S lock, is compatible with existing S lock held by T1, therefore is granted. 3) T1 requests X lock. This is incompatible with the S lock granted to T2 at step 2, so it waits. 4) T2 requests X lock, it is incompatible with the S lock granted to T1 at step 1, so it waits. Deadlock:T1 waits on T2 from step 3, T2 waits on T1 from step 4.

Comment: The fact that the S locks granted at step 1) and 2) are held for the duration of the transaction is caused by your OperationBehavior transaction scope. W/o that the S locks would be immediately released. this would eliminate the deadlock, but your application would assume that the state it read is the last state and T2 would simply overwrite T1 changes (lost updates).

Comment: @cyberkiwi: If the IDs are different you have a only a *probability* to deadlock, due to hash collisions: http://rusanu.com/2009/05/29/lockres-collision-probability-magic-marker-16777215. But if the ids are different, then yo don't really need any locking at all. The only interesting case for correctness is when two requests try to modify the same id.

Comment: @remus - If the ids are different - would this still deadlock? OP could be wrong, but did state that they will operate on different ids (I'm testing using `Level Serializable` without using TABLOCK - does `OperationBehavior(TransactionScopeRequired` equate to `WITH(TABLOCK)`?)

Comment: @remus I was trying to edit, couldn't, so delete-added the modified comment. I have read your (very good) article. I was just wondering because you said **"guaranteed"** deadlock

Comment: `OperationBehavior(TrannsactionScopeRequired)`  implies a new TransactionScope with default ctor arguments. This implies serializable transaction. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: @cyberkiwi: I said guaranteed because I've seen what the OP was doing. My guess is that he/she is testing (the sleep is trying to emulate some lengthy processing) and is making calls with the same ID to see the behavior.

Comment: So assuming OP retests according to _`For one thing, the two transactions accessed and operated on different rows.`_, it should be ok? collisions on int columns should be pretty rare, and more rare the smaller the source table. *[ps @cyberkiwi doesn't ping me]*

Comment: @Richard:well, why did you change your moniker? If the OP has a way to guarantee that the transactions operate and access distinct IDs, then he need no locks to start with. The locking is exactly for this case, when two concurrent requests attempt to operate on the same ID, and in this case the deadlocks is guaranteed.

Comment: @remus Don't get me wrong, I agree with you 100% and believe you are spot on (on what is actually happening vs what is stated). Trying to see if the OP has a way out, for example by following the "spec" and testing properly (different IDs and/or removing TransactionScope)! [the moniker changed weeks ago..]

Comment: @remus Also helping visitors (searching via "Deadlock") to connect the dots between the question text and your answer (which contains implicit assumptions disputing the *question text*)

Comment: Sorry for not replying sooner. As stated in my original post, IDs are indeed different. I realize I don't need transaction due to different Ids, but I'm learning and as such trying to figure out how things behave.

Comment: A – "2) T2 requests S lock, is compatible with existing S lock held by T1, therefore is granted" a1 - Compatible how? a2 - Are the two locks held b T1 and T2 basically one and the same lock, or just identical?

Comment: B - "4) T2 requests X lock, it is incompatible with the S lock granted to T1 at step 1, so it waits" b1 - You mean X lock is incompatible with T1's S lock? But if that is the case, then X lock is also incompatible with T2's S lock, since if the two S locks are compatible, then if one S lock is incompatible with X lock, then so is the other?! b2 - Anyways, what does incompatible mean in this context? or that T2's Incompatible how?

Comment: If you have no indexes then the GetState call will lock in S mode the *entire table*. You must have a clustered index on `id`

Comment: I think I somewhat understand it now,thought I'd appreciate if you could correct me if I'm wrong. Anyways, here's how I understand it: If X lock is to be used on particular resource, then no other lock can be held on that same resource. Thus in order for T1 to acquire X lock, it needs to relase its own S lock. But since T1 "notices" that T2 also has a S lock, it decides to wait for T2's S lock to get released before releasing its own S lock. And since T2 is »thinking« the same, a deadlock situation occurs?!

Comment: BTW - instead of T1 waiting for T2's S lock to be released, why doesn't T1 first release its own S lock and then wait for T2's lock to get released?

Comment: T1 can upgrade its own lock from S to X at any moment if he was alone, because T1 is always compatible with itslef, on all lock modes. But because T2 *also* has an S lock, T1 cannot upgrade its lock to X. It is T2's S lock that blocks the granting of the X lock, not it's own S lock.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Much appreciate your detailed explanation, but I disagree the probability lock is not interesting "for correctness". Perhaps you are an academic? ;-) In the real world, few people cares whether their software doesn't work because of a probabilistic lock or a guaranteed one. Also, many concurrent clients could lead to lock escalation and thus cause deadlocks even with 0 hash collisions. Then again, most coders seem to prefer to abandon serializable isolation and hope nobody ever figures out the strange incidents nobody can reproduce...